# How to redirect to app using Supabase OAuth with Flutter on Windows and MacOS

Tags: windows, flutter, macos, oauth, supabase

Here is how we do a Sign In with Oauth on supabase_flutter:

```
bool result = await supabase.auth.signInWithOAuth(Provider.google,redirectTo: redirectTo);
```

It works with Android ('com.mianala.playlist://login-callback/') but how do I redirect it to my windows or macos app?

Comment: How you do to redirect to app in android? can you put an example of your code, and how it is configure on supabase?

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered specifying the authScreenLaunchMode parameter? The authScreenLaunchMode takes a value of the LaunchMode type.

here is LaunchMode.

```
enum LaunchMode {
  /// Leaves the decision of how to launch the URL to the platform
  /// implementation.
  platformDefault,

  /// Loads the URL in an in-app web view (e.g., Safari View Controller).
  inAppWebView,

  /// Passes the URL to the OS to be handled by another application.
  externalApplication,

  /// Passes the URL to the OS to be handled by another non-browser application.
  externalNonBrowserApplication,
}
```

Comment: inAppWebView isn't supported on Windows.  There's some custom-url parsing functionality that needs to be implemented that I'm doing some research on now.  It's interesting.  I did not expect this to be so difficult out of the box, but I'm new to Flutter.